# Computing Camera Matrix Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, camera, computer-vision, projection

I'm currently trying to compute the camera matrix P given a set of world points (X) with its corresponding image points (x). However, when testing for the the result, P (3 x 4 camera matrix) multiplying by the world points does not give me the correct corresponding image points. However, only the first column of PX = x. The other column won't return the approximate image points.

Code:

```
X = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 1 1 1];
x = [3 2 1; 6 5 4; 1 1 1];

[mX, nX] = size(X);
[mx, nx] = size(x);

for i = 0:(nX-1)
  XX{i+1} = transpose(X(1+i: 4+i));
end

for i = 0:(nx-1)
  xx{i+1} = transpose(x(i+1:3+i));
end

%TODO - normalization

A = [];
%construct matrix
for i = 1:nX
  A = [A; zeros(1,4) -1*(xx{i}(3)*transpose(XX{i})) xx{i}(2)*transpose(XX{i})];
  A = [A; xx{i}(3)*transpose(XX{i}) zeros(1,4) -1*xx{i}(1)*transpose(XX{i})];
end

%using svd to solve for non zero solution
[u s v] = svd(A);

p = v(:, size(v,2));
p = reshape(p, 4,3)';
```

output for the first column, works good:

```
>> p*XX{1}

ans =

    0.0461
    0.0922
    0.0154

>> ans/0.0154

ans =

    2.9921
    5.9841
    0.9974

>> xx{1}

ans =

     3
     6
     1
```

output for the second column, doesn't work:

```
>> p*XX{2}

ans =

    0.5202
    0.0867
    0.1734

>> ans/0.1734

ans =

    2.9999
    0.5000
    1.0000

>> xx{2}

ans =

     6
     1
     2
```

By the way, I was told that I need to normalize the world points and image points before I compute the camera matrix. I have not done this step and have no idea how to. If this is causing the issue, please explain what can be done. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please someone!

Comment: Maybe wrong indexing in `x(i+1:3+i)`. Run this piece alone in command window. Is that what you want?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, now it works well! Thank you for your thorough answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: @xiavinson no problem at all.  If you like I can talk about why you need to normalize points.  However, I feel that it should be a separate question.  In this particular instance, the magnitude of the values between your 2D and 3D points is roughly the same so normalization is not required.

Comment: @rayryeng I've ask a professor. He said normalization the points would reduce the numerical errors in calculating the camera matrix. I kind of get why, sort of like standardization in stats?

Comment: @xiavinson Yes that's correct. This boils down to the magnitude of the points from 3D to 2D.  Remember that this is a linear transform, so if your 3D points are quite large and if your 2D points are quite small, a small change in 3D will be quite a large change in 2D.  The same thing if the 3D points are small and the 2D points are large.  Therefore, normalization ensures that both points are within the same scale so that finding the camera matrix escapes this sensitivity in different magnitudes.  You would of course need to **unnormalize** the points after projecting with the camera matrix.

Comment: @xiavinson There are also quite a few ways to normalize the points.  One way that is commonly done is to normalize each set of points (2D and 3D independently) such that they exhibit zero mean, unit variance... or standardization as you are aware of.  [Richard Hartley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Hartley_(scientist)) suggests zero mean, but ensuring that the average distance from the new centroid (zero mean) to each of the points is `sqrt(2)`.  In his paper on [the defense of the 8-point algorithm](https://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS485/Handouts/hartley.pdf), he discusses why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you aren't indexing into the matrix properly.  You are using linear indexing to access each column of the matrix.  In that case, your `for` loop needs to access each column independently.  Therefore, each iteration of your `for` loop must access groups of 4 elements for your 3D points and groups of 3 elements for your 2D points.

As such, you simply need to do this for your `for` loops:

```
for i = 0:(nX-1)
    XX{i+1} = transpose(X(4*i + 1 : 4*(i + 1)));
end

for i = 0:(nx-1)
    xx{i+1} = transpose(x(3*i + 1 : 3*(i + 1)));
end
```

After this, the code should work no problem.  To verify, we can loop through each 3D point and determine its 2D equivalent as you're using cells:

```
out = zeros(size(xx)); % Declare output matrix
for ii = 1 : numel(XX) % For each 3D point...
    out(:,ii) = p * XX{ii}; % Transform the point
    out(:,ii) = out(:,ii) / out(end,ii); % Normalize
end
```

We thus get:

```
>> out

out =

    3.0000    2.0000    1.0000
    6.0000    5.0000    4.0000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

Compare with your `x`:

```
>> x

x =

     3     2     1
     6     5     4
     1     1     1
```

## Suggestion - Use vectorization

If I can suggest something, please do not use cell arrays here.  You can create the matrix of equations for solving using vectorization.  Specifically, you can create the matrix `A` directly without any `for` loops:

```
A = [zeros(N, 4) -X.' bsxfun(@times, x(2,:).', X.'); 
     X.' zeros(N, 4) bsxfun(@times, -x(1,:).', X.')];
```

If you own MATLAB R2016b and up, you can do this with internal broadcasting:

```
A = [zeros(N, 4) -X.' x(2,:).' .* X.'; 
     X.' zeros(N, 4) -x(1,:).' .* X.']
```

Note that you will see the rows are shuffled in comparison to your original matrix `A` because of the vectorization.  Because we are solving for the null space of the matrix `A`, shuffling the rows has no effect.  Therefore, your code can be simplified to:

```
X = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 1 1 1];
x = [3 2 1; 6 5 4; 1 1 1];

A = [zeros(N, 4) -X.' bsxfun(@times, x(2,:).', X.'); 
     X.' zeros(N, 4) bsxfun(@times, -x(1,:).', X.')];

% Use this for MATLAB R2016b and up
% A = [zeros(N, 4) -X.' x(2,:).' .* X.'; 
%      X.' zeros(N, 4) -x(1,:).' .* X.']

[u, s, v] = svd(A);
p = v(:, end);
p = reshape(p, 4, 3).';
```

To finally compute the output matrix, you can just use simple matrix multiplication. The fact that you are using cells requires that you have to use a `for` loop and it's much faster to do this with matrix multiplication:

```
out = p * X;
```

You can then take the last row of the results and divide each of the other rows by this row.

```
out = bsxfun(@rdivide, out, out(end,:));
```

Again with MATLAB R2016b and up, you can just do it as so:

```
out = out ./ out(end,:);
```